# Horror movie about a robot kid with claws for hands

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

A long time ago I saw a horror movie, and I don't remember the name. I have been looking for it for three years, but I haven't found it.

I think I remember that the film was about a man who made a robot kid or something similar, with big claws. The man died (I don't remember why), and the man's daughter took care of the robot.

The scene that I remember the most is one where the robot strokes a cat to death.

Comment: Claws? Or maybe blades? Sounds like Edward Scissorhands.

Comment: yeah I though the same when I was searching it and I check that movie but I didn't find any scene like the one that I mentioned so I descarted it :(

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when and where you saw this?

Comment: @ArlettaS +1 Definitely sounds like  Edward Scissorhands to me.

Answer (score 8):

[*Simon_Says (The_Outer_Limits)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Says_(The_Outer_Limits)),
found this on [*reddit*](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/6b2536/tomt_tv_show_or_movie_robot_kills_cat_at_endclimax/)

[*Scene on youtube - robot pets cat to death...*](https://youtu.be/_suB-c0cDV0?t=212)

> Gideon Banks, an electronic engineer, twenty years ago lost his wife
> Liz and son Simon in a horrific car crash. At that period of time he
> was working at the so-called Neural Archiving Project — NAP for short.
> This technology was developed to create smart computers by
> transferring human engrams into computers.
>
> The company eventually gave up on the technology, but Gideon didn't.
> After years of quietly perfecting it, he built at home a small robot,
> using parts he stole from Concorde Robotics, where he now works. Zoe,
> Gideon's niece, discovers Gideon's secret, that the robot contains
> actual neural engrams from Gideon's dead son Simon, which Gideon has
> integrated into the robot in hopes of re-creating his son. And now,
> the robot actually has memories of the real Simon.
>
> Zoe becomes worried not only about Gideon but also about the robot
> that sounds and acts a lot like her little cousin used to. And she
> begins to realize that Simon may not have been the lovable little
> angel that everyone believed he was.
>
> "Simon" becomes more and more demanding, putting pressure on Gideon,
> who could lose his job. When he asks Zoe to "babysit," the robot
> attacks during a tantrum and injures her. When Gideon returns they
> argue about "Simon" being a robot or as Gideon insists, a true boy.
> Zoe leaves upset. Later, Gideon apologizes over the phone and asks her
> to look after Simon again as he has to work. Zoe does so, but this
> time gets along much better with "Simon" who also apologizes for
> hurting her.
>
> Gideon's boss finds out about the robot, and claims that since it was
> built from company equipment, it belongs to the company. When he tries
> to forcibly take "Simon" away, Gideon becomes enraged and clubs the
> man on the head, killing him. Gideon and Zoe begin to argue, but
> "Simon", who becomes distraught at recognizing the seriousness of the
> situation, shouts for them to stop and claims that he is ultimately
> the one at fault. Upset, "Simon" confesses that "he" was responsible
> for the car crash: when Liz refused to take Simon to the toy store,
> Simon threw a temper tantrum and grabbed the steering wheel, causing
> the fatal crash. To him, that unwise tantrum was the first domino to
> start the chain reaction that has now led to this moment.
>
> Realizing what he's done could seriously impact Zoe, Gideon ushers her
> out, assuring her that he'll remedy the situation and do the right
> thing without affecting her. Soon afterwards, Zoe hears a gunshot and
> rushes back in, only to discover that Gideon has copied his own mind
> into another robot before committing suicide. Zoe can only look on in
> horrified silence as the two robots chat like father and son.